# Using devise scope to redefine default routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Geting an error when trying to redefine the session routes using devise scopes.

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :users do
  get    '/login'   => 'devise/sessions#new',     as: :new_user_session
  post   '/login'   => 'devise/sessions#create',  as: :user_session
  delete '/logout'  => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
end
```

The error.

`` Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes ``

I understand the error just not why its happening. wouldn't the scope redefine the as new_user_session?

Also if you follow the wiki you will get a devise deprecation warning for passing a block. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guess I needed to skip the sessions 
`devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. If you pay attention `devise_scope` model must be singular and `devise_for` plural. So the solution is:

```rb
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Misread the question a bit.
You should be able to pass a :controllers option hash to devise_for if you're overriding a devise controller. It's fine to have your new controller inherit from the original.

If you're just trying to change the paths, you wouldn't want to use devise_scope. Something like the following should work in that case:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => :account, :path_names => {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register'} # 'account/login' replaces 'users/sign_in', etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution may be add **"as"** option to devise_for

```
devise_for :users, as: "some_prefix"
```